# How to apply margin to child div without affecting parent div?

Tags: css, html, margin

I am trying to apply margin to specific child div 2**"#child2"** but it applies margin to parent div too. Problem is margin collapse.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1" class="child">hello1</div>
  <div id="child2" class="child">hello1</div>
  <div id="child3" class="child">hello1</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent{
  overflow:auto;
  padding-top: -1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
.child{
  margin:0 30px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #5395ce;
  padding: 5px;
}
#parent{
  background-color: #000;
}
#child2{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Here is the code: http://jsbin.com/nibaw/5/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Can you post the code please. Seems like I can't access the link (may be security issue in my PC)

Comment: if you are unable to tell what you want you plz add screen shot that how you want..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Define your**  **your** `.child` class `vertical-align:top;`

```
.child{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: this is awesome. thnx.

Comment: @Orahmax: When you use `display:inline-block` then make sure to vertically align elements.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
#child2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

which is adding 15px  top margin.

Comment: I have to apply that margin as per design needs so i wanted to solve margin-collapse problem. i can't remove margin from child div.